# How do redirect to a new page If check boxed is checked?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, force.com

[image]

I want to redirect to a new page **(pagebpc)** when user hit Save and Review button if above check box is checked. Otherwise it should goes to view page as it is on the extension. How do you add code for if it is checked, redirect to new and, If it is not, just the way it is. Thanks

**input field for check box**

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Bioprocess_Container_Customization_Reqd__c}" />
```

**Save Button**

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Save & Review" action="{!next}"/>
```

**Extension**

```
 public PageReference next() {
    if(controller.save() == null) {
    return null;}
    PageReference ref = Page.gibcopb2;
    ref.getParameters().put('id', controller.getId());
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    return ref;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `controller` is a reference to the [StandardController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm):

```
public PageReference next() {
    if (controller.save() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Product_Brief__c pb = (Product_Brief__c) controller.getRecord();
    if (pb.Bioprocess_Container_Customization_Reqd__c) {
        PageReference ref = Page.bpc;
        // Add any parameters required here
        return ref;
    } else {
        PageReference ref = Page.gibcopb2;
        ref.getParameters().put('id', controller.getId());
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works exactly the way I want it.